# docker run: how to pass variable values to sh -c

Tags: docker

I am trying to replace the variable value before the sh command

```
url="google.com"
docker run --rm -it \
--volume="/home/administrator/tmp:/home/simha:rw" \
someimage /bin/sh -c 'ping "${url}"'
```

FInally I want to do

```
sh -c 'ping google.com'
```

So how to substiture the url value in the above.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the value in single quotes, your host shell won't interpret it; but you're not passing it into the image, so it's not in the container's environment either.

Here I'd suggest removing the `sh -c` wrapper on the container command, and just running the command you mean.

```bash
# set a shell variable in the host shell
url=https://google.com

# launch the container; have the host shell inject that variable
docker run --rm \
  someimage \
  curl "$url"
```

If you really want a shell inside the container to expand the variable, you need to arrange to pass the variable into the container.  One straightforward approach is to use the `docker run -e` option instead of the host-shell variable

```bash
docker run --rm \
  -e url=https://google.com \
  someimage \
  sh -c 'curl "$url"'
```

Or `docker run -e name` without a value will copy an environment variable from the host into the container; in a shell context note that the variable must be `export`ed.

```bash
url=https://google.com
export url

docker run --rm \
  -e url \
  someimage \
  sh -c 'curl "$url"'
```

Comment: (Note that I've consistently used an actual URL for the `url` variable, and I've used **curl**(1) to make HTTP requests.  The **ping**(1) tool sends packets using a very low-level protocol called ICMP, which is sometimes blocked by routers even if normal TCP connections can get through fine, and it doesn't actually try to connect to an application; it's not usually the debugging tool you want.)

Comment: Missing a closing single quote on the very last sample?